# How do I stop a Git commit when VI is on the screen waiting for a commit message?

Tags: git

I have asked Git to perform a commit from within git bash, It has brought up VI as it always does.

I now wish to cancel the commit, how do I prevent proceeding with the commit from this point?

Comment: Worth adding that you need to pres Esc prior to entering `:q!` to exit vim.

Answer (score 411, accepted):

You have two options:

- Provide an empty commit message. If it's a new commit and you haven't yet saved the message, you can simply use `:q!` (quit without saving). If you’ve already saved (or you're amending a previous commit), just delete the entire log message and save again. This can be done with <kbd>ggdG</kbd> + `:wq` in Vim.
- Have the editor exit with a non-zero exit code. In Vim, you can use `:cq` (quit with an error code).

It's worth noting that you can always reset your working copy to the state it was in before the commit with `git reset HEAD^`.

Comment: :cq is the business. For some reason git ploughs on regardless if i use :q!

Comment: git reset HEAD^ would discard local modifications

Comment: :q! probably doesn't work because there is a predefined message already there, you are just editing it.

Comment: Hiccup: If `git reset HEAD^` asks for more, your shell may interpret ^ as line continuation.  Try `git reset "HEAD^"`, `git reset HEAD^^`, or `git reset HEAD~1` instead per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203952/git-reset-asks-more

Answer (score 123):

- `:q!` does not work when amending a commit. It does not update the
  commit message, but it executes the amendment :-(
- `:cq` completely aborts the amendment.

Comment: I wish I could add another +1. I've been here multitudes of time when my amend picks up the wrong commit.

Comment: :q! actually saving changes makes me sad. Leaky abstraction

Answer (score 11):

To sum up:

- **When creating a new commit** (i.e `git commit`) quit using `:q!`.
- **When amending** (i.e. `git commit --amend`) remove the commit message (only the first few rows **not** beginning with a #) for example by holding v and using arrow keys to select it and then pressing Delete. **Quit with `:wq` to apply changes**! If you use `:q!` the changes will be lost and the previous commit message will be used.

When using VIM it's ok in both cases to quit with `:cq` - VIM will quit with an error code and the commit will be aborted.

Answer (score 0):

All answers are trying to teach you a bit of `vim`

but if you really have a problem closing a `vim`

you can have much more problems with the edition

and the situation will be repeated on every interaction in git

so **you'd like to change a git editor**

`git config --global core.editor nano`

`git config --global core.editor <your_editor>`

or learn editors like vim or emacs.