# How to completely remove a file from git if you already pushed it to the remote branch, merged to the develop branch and it is not the latest commit

Tags: git

I've seen a lot of tutorials explaining how to do this in different scenarios but seems like many of them talk of the latest commit. So what I need is to remove this sensitive file completely from both branches: `feature-branch` and `develop`.

How do I do that?

I've found this recipe:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch path_to_file" HEAD
```

Will it work in my case? Namely, will it completely remove this file from all the branches?

EDIT:

I've decided to use BFG and here's the output it has given me after I run

`bfg --delete-files 'filename_of_the_file_to_delete'`

output:

```
Found 273 objects to protect
Found 198 commit-pointing refs : HEAD, refs/heads/develop, refs/heads/develop-with-relative-paths, ...

Protected commits
-----------------

These are your protected commits, and so their contents will NOT be altered:

 * commit 7d97ab00 (protected by 'HEAD') - contains 1 dirty file :
    - src/email/filename_of_the_file_to_delete (16.1 KB)

WARNING: The dirty content above may be removed from other commits, but as
the *protected* commits still use it, it will STILL exist in your repository.

Details of protected dirty content have been recorded here :

/Users/albert/Documents/projects/rjx/rjxfp/.git.bfg-report/2020-08-25/21-50-38/protected-dirt/

If you *really* want this content gone, make a manual commit that removes it, and then run the BFG on a fresh copy of your repo.


Cleaning
--------

Found 486 commits
Cleaning commits:       100% (486/486)
Cleaning commits completed in 699 ms.

Updating 7 Refs
---------------

    Ref                                                    Before     After
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    refs/heads/develop                                   | e9c3c4ba | 53c5dd39
    refs/heads/feature-icons-for-top-level-cats          | d7dde80c | 377ae820
    refs/heads/feature-user-profile                      | 7d97ab00 | e3b1b336
    refs/remotes/origin/develop                          | e9c3c4ba | 53c5dd39
    refs/remotes/origin/feature-icons-for-top-level-cats | d7dde80c | 377ae820
    refs/remotes/origin/feature-user-profile             | 7d97ab00 | e3b1b336
    refs/stash                                           | 9fc9a356 | 39945789

Updating references:    100% (7/7)
...Ref update completed in 54 ms.

Commit Tree-Dirt History
------------------------

    Earliest                                              Latest
    |                                                          |
    ..........................................................DD

    D = dirty commits (file tree fixed)
    m = modified commits (commit message or parents changed)
    . = clean commits (no changes to file tree)

                            Before     After
    -------------------------------------------
    First modified commit | 6a211a6b | 35597e71
    Last dirty commit     | e9c3c4ba | 53c5dd39

Deleted files
-------------

    Filename                          Git id
    ------------------------------------------------------
    filename_of_the_file_to_delete    | 4121d724 (16.1 KB)


In total, 37 object ids were changed. Full details are logged here:

    /Users/albert/Documents/projects/rjx/rjxfp/.git.bfg-report/2020-08-25/21-50-38

BFG run is complete! When ready, run: git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

The file I wanted to delete is still in the directory where it was created, at least on the branch from which I ran the `bfg` command. Then I don't think I completely understand what it says about some protected dirty content. Who protected it and why?
It says: `If you *really* want this content gone, make a manual commit that removes it, and then run the BFG on a fresh copy of your repo.`

I don't understand what I should do exactly.

As far as I understand, the commit it mentioned `7d97ab00` (which is now `e3b1b336`) is the last commit on the branch from which I ran the command, so I have to remove the file (but do I have to remove it with `rm` or `git-rm`?) then make a commit and run BFG again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: Remove committed file after push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357511/git-remove-committed-file-after-push)

Comment: @puffin As far as I understand, this answer is applicable if we speak of the latest commit and like I said I made a merge, so this tutorial is not my case.

Comment: The simplest solution is to rollback the merge into `develop`, follow these instructions for `feature-branch`, and redo the merge after the sensitive info is removed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove file from Git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762338/how-to-remove-file-from-git-history) I recommend the [BFG repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

Comment: Its not recommended to use filter branch since its slow and tends to mangle your history, see the [`filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) docs. It suggests using [`filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/)

Comment: @puffin Would you please write the whole command? Will it be enough to change `filter-branch` to `filter-repo`? There're not too many commits in the repository, maybe about 500 commits.

Comment: @Albert, no you'll need to install a git extension. You can read more [here](https://www.mankier.com/1/git-filter-repo) `git filter-repo --filename-callback 'if filename == <filename>: return None'`

Comment: @Thomas I've decided to use `BFG` but I need to clarify something, would you please have a look?

Comment: There are branches , where you want to keep the file? E.g. master?

Comment: @Christoph No, I want it to be removed entirely from the project, that's to say, not a single branch should have it.

Comment: @Christoph I've made an update in the question. Would you please have a look?

Comment: Whats the difference to the duplicate then? Delete the file, commit and remove it.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I've managed to remove the file off the project, thanks for reminding me of BFG, nice tool. The case was not a trivial one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't used The BFG, I understand from its documentation that it considers the tip-most commit of each branch to be a "correct state".  That is, suppose you want to remove the file `secret.txt` from every commit.  If you use The BFG with the instruction "remove file `secret.txt`", it will remove it from all commits *except* the current commit (and any other branch-tip commit that has that file in it).

Remember that *branch names* simply identify some commit, by its commit hash ID.  It's the *commit itself* that has the files in it.  Every commit has a full snapshot of *every* file.  So if you added `secret.txt` four commits ago, and have this:

```
... <-H <-I <-J <-K <-L   <--master
```

where each uppercase letter stands in for a commit, the file `secret.txt` is in commits `L`, `K`, `J`, and `I`.  It's not in `H` because `H` is *five* commits ago.

The backwards-pointing arrows here are how Git works: every commit leads *backwards* to the *previous* commit.  No part of any commit can ever be changed (not by The BFG either), so what The BFG must do is to create *new and improved* commits, then throw out the old commits entirely.

The BFG will copy existing commit `I` to a new-and-improved `I'` in which `secret.txt` does not exist.  It will then copy `J` to a new-and-improved `J'` in which `secret.txt` does not exist, and repeat this for `K`.  But `L` is the *last* commit, identified by name, so The BFG assumes that you mean to *keep* `secret.txt` there, because it's there now *and* identified by name.  This is the "protected" commit.  So The BFG copies `L` to `L'`—it has to do this because it copied `K` to `K'` and the existing `L` points back to the existing `K`—but this time it keeps `secret.txt` in commit `L'`.

You end up with:

```
... <-H [ XXX deleted: <-I <-J <-K <-L ]
       \
        I' <-J' <-K' <-L'   <-- master
```

in which `secret.txt` now exists only in that last commit, `L'`, that was protected.

The documentation for The BFG suggests that you do this:

```
git rm secret.txt
git commit
```

*before you start*, so that you start with:

```
... <-H <-I <-J <-K <-L <-M   <--master
```

where new commit `M` *doesn't* have `secret.txt` in it.  Now commits `I` through `L` can all be fixed-up, because `L` *isn't* the *last* commit any more.  It is not identified by name.  The name `master` finds, not `L`, but `M`; only `M` itself finds `L`.

#### Notes

Once you've updated your own repository to have new-and-improved commits, and have thrown out the old bad ones, you will need to use `git push --force` to get any *other* Git that still has, and is still using, the old bad commits, to switch to the new and improved commits.

Always assume that if `secrets.txt` was available on the web for even a few seconds, *someone* out there grabbed a copy of it.

Comment: Wow, grand explanation! Thank you a lot!