# Delete Repository and history

Tags: gitlab

I had to upload my php code to my GitLab project for my university class. Unfortunately I uploaded the wrong data and now I just want to delete all of the data again und upload my new correct data. When I deleted the data manually I still be able to see them in the history. So is there a way to just delete everything I just uploaded? And I am not allowed to delete the whole project because other members have some subprojects.

I am using Windows 10 by the way.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: Remove committed file after push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357511/git-remove-committed-file-after-push)

Comment: Okay I could undo the last steps of my uploads with these commands. But now I cannot delete the first step (my first upload). When I type in "git checkout HEAD^ /c/php-docker/" I get the error: error: pathspec 'HEAD^' did not match any file(s) known to git

Comment: Ok it worked! This video helped me! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRttZswoJrQ&ab_channel=ztfWilliam
Thanks anyway!