# .gitignore and "exclude"-File doesn't work (JetBrains Rider)

Tags: gitignore, jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm working on a project with multiple people and we want to exclude some files from pushing into our branches. Now I tried to use a GitIgnore-File and/or a exclude-File, both don't work.

The content of both files are identical.

[image: Image of gitignore:]

Comment: If they are already on the remote, you need to remove them like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51417945/7938503). Afterward, they will be ignored.

Comment: Hmmm. They are needed in the project, but all new changes should not be pushed.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43535767/7938503) then.