# How can I remove last two commits in git and get my commit 1 as changes in working directory?

Tags: linux, git, version-control

**Here is the scenario:**

1. On a smallish Ubuntu web server I have a git server running. The website is checked out from git repository. I had a bulk of changes that I added and committed. Git diff showed 50+ code files updated and 20000+ image files. I did not paid much attention to this thinking these should be ignored, my fault. A bit stupid but I thought it was quickest to just commit all changes as a bulk. Let's call it commit A

`# Commit A
git add .
git commit -m "Changes so far in this year"`

2. I discovered that I forgot to exclude working/output files (huge number of generated images). Other than these files (around 20000) I had about 50+ files with code changes.
3. After reading online and git manual I understood that best bet was to update .gitignore and generate a list of files to remove and remove cached. This should  remove from commit but not the local folder. Let this be commit B

`# Commit B
vi .gitignore
git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached
git add .
git commit -m "Cleanup of generated files from commit history"`

4. Trouble is that now my git push fails with following error

`git push origin master
Counting objects: 19219, done.
error: pack-objects died of signal 9
error: pack-objects died with strange error
error: child process died of signal 9
error:  died of signal 9
error: failed to push some refs to '/srv/gitrepositories/xxxx.git'`

Answers on this [question about error 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985124/git-push-error-index-pack-died-of-signal-9) suggests it might be due to git running out of memory.

**My options?**

- Is commit A & commit B made up of huge
  number of objects, which looking at the count above it seems?
- Is there a better way to clean this mess up with possible option to remove commit A & commit B altogether from history and get my changes intact?
- Idealy I want to go back to stage where my git diff reports only the 50+ code files. Images are now ignored by .gitignore
- [Can I delete a git commit but keep the changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772134/can-i-delete-a-git-commit-but-keep-the-changes) Is this what it sounds like? Can I do it twice for both commit A and commit B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `git reset HEAD~2` to clear the last 2 commit from history permanently while keeping the changes in the working directory, then `git push -f` to force push your changed history to the remote.

If your repo is shared with others it's not advisable to change your commit history.

Comment: Thanks, the repo is not shared. The commits are not pushed yet.
Would `git reset HEAD~2` mean that we will only be left with uncommitted changes and no commit history for A & B?

Comment: Yes. It will be like the same state as right before you made the 2 commits. Changes will be kept in working directory.