# git reset --soft HEAD^ is not undoing my commit

Tags: git, github, commit

I'm trying to undo a commit and duplicate the commit, but when I use

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

(as it was explained to me) it appears this question: ***More?***
When it was being explained to me, the ***More?*** statement wasn't mentioned. What does this means? Do I have to add something else to undo my commit?

Comment: Are you using Windows? Maybe this answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203952/git-reset-asks-more

Comment: @lleon yes i am using windows, i'll check the link, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below mentioned:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3
```

The last three commits (HEAD, HEAD^, and HEAD~2) were bad and you do not want to ever see them again. Do not do this if you have already given these commits to somebody else.

Comment: what if i just use git reset --soft "HEAD^" like i saw in the link that @lleon gave me? Is it not enough?