# Exit Vim without committing changes in Git

Tags: git, vim, git-commit

When I use `git commit --amend` or `git rebase -i`, vim opens up for me to make changes. If I then change my mind and exit vim without making any changes, a commit is still made which shows up in `git reflog`.

How do I exit the editor without committing anything?

Comment: Note that `git reflog` is local to that working copy.  It's the chronological history of your HEAD rather than the logical history.

Comment: git commits when it detects the temp file has changed (been saved). The more simple question here is "How do I exit vim without saving?"  The answer, as gpojd has shown, is `:q!`.

Comment: git replaces the previous commit(the hash tag changes) even if I exit without saving.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop a Git commit when VI is on the screen waiting for a commit message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323440/how-do-i-stop-a-git-commit-when-vi-is-on-the-screen-waiting-for-a-commit-message)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To get git to not make a change when you are executing `git commit --amend` or `git rebase -i`.

Just delete the message (and save). All git does is look for a non empty message to see if a valid commit happened. Since there is a commit message (because you commited something before) git thinks that its a valid commit or rebase.

Comment: do I \delete the comments also or just the non-comment part?

Comment: @Shanimal non comments is sufficent.

Answer (score 93):

```
:cq!
```

This will force an error to Vim and it will not save any changes. [Link](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:cq) to Vim manual.

**You may want to use `cq` without `!` if you want `vim` to exit with an error and without saving.**

Comment: +++++++ amazing!

Comment: You should use `cq` with the `!`it forces vim to save whereas without `!` it closes the editor with an error without saving.

Answer (score 32):

When you haven't made changes and saved them, `:q!` could suffice (in a plain commit; when you're not amending), but if you are like me, chances are you've already (even unconsciously) persisted the edited message.

Git (and other such tools that use Vim to edit a message) will abort the entire process (and ignore any saved changes to the message) if the editor quits with a non-success exit status. You can do that in Vim with the `:cq[uit]!` command.

**You may want to use `cq` without `!` if you want `vim` to exit with an error and without saving.**

Comment: +1 for `:cq`, but -1 for `:q!` - this isn't correct, it just keeps the pre-amended commit message and applies any actual staged changes.

Comment: @CharlesBailey For amend, you're right, but for plain commits, the empty message will prevent Git from committing. I intended my first sentence as a lead-in towards the actual answer; the discussion in gpjod's answer already showed its problems. But thanks for highlighting this once more!

Comment: OK, but the whole question is about the 'amend' case only, so I think it's a little misleading to mention it at all; at least without saying something like "if you're **not** amending..." first.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Thank you for badgering me towards a better answer; I've incorporated your suggestion; hopefully, I've earned your +1 now :-)

Comment: This baffles me that the usual `:q!` doesn't work here, as it does in the case of a normal commit!? I just mangled my repo amending uncommitted added files I wasn't aware of, because of that.

Answer (score 4):

the git appication runs the editor application, and if the editor application returnes unsuccessfully (non-zero exitcode) the git application recognizes this and stops further processing.

in vim you can perform this with `:cq!`

from the vim manual:

```
                                                        :cq :cquit 
:cq[uit][!]             Quit Vim with an error code, so that the compiler
                        will not compile the same file again.
                        WARNING: All changes in files are lost!  Also when the
                        [!] is not used.  It works like ":qall!" :qall,
                        except that Vim returns a non-zero exit code.
```

this works for svn, too! the difference AFAIK between svn and git is, that svn don't like empty commit messages and stops when you quit with `:q!` (even if the exitcode is 0) but for git this is ok. for both it is not ok, if the editor gives an non-zero exitcode.

exitcodes are a very fundamental concept in unix/linux and and easy way to inform the caller application if everyhing was ok (exitcode 0) or something went wrong.

Comment: You should use `cq` with the `!` it forces vim to save whereas without `!` it closes the editor with an error without saving.