# How to abort a git rebase from inside vim during interactive editing

Tags: git, vim, git-rebase

When I do an interactive rebase, e.g.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

the rebase interactive editor (vim in my case) opens to let me edit the commits to rebase

```
pick c843ea2 Set Vim column limit to 80 (OS X)
pick fc32eac Add Bash alias for `pbcopy` (OS X)
....
```

If I now decide that I want to abort the rebase and quit vim using `:q` the rebase starts anyway. I'm using git version `1.9.0.msysgit.0` on windows.

Sure I can just delete all `pick` lines, but it might be a lot to do if I rebase a longer history. Is there another way?

How can I quit the rebase interactive editor (vim) and abort the rebase?

Comment: Would you prefer to use a different editor, such as Notepad? If so, I have a solution for that

Comment: `git rebase --abort `

Comment: @vanduc1102 Works for me, wish it was an answer!

Answer (score 371, accepted):

If you exit the editor with an error code, the rebase will be aborted.

To exit with an error code on vim, do

```
:cq
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595908/git-exit-vim-without-commiting) and vimdoc [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:cq).

Answer (score 53):

Just delete all the lines that are not comments from the file. Then save it to the default supplied path and exit the editor.

As a result git will just do nothing in this rebase.

To delete all lines in vim you can use

```
:%d|x
```

Then save and quit.

[delete all lines of file in Vim](http://choorucode.com/2011/04/18/how-to-delete-all-lines-of-file-in-vim)

[How to exit the Vim editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11828270/#11828573)

[VIM - multiple commands on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3249275/#3249303)

Comment: this is not the case for the merge commits. try doing the interactive rebase to include at least one merge commit and compare the result with the original state.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using Notepad++ on Windows for instance:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to select everything, then <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> save. Git will abort the rebase if the file is empty.

You may also hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in the command prompt where git is running to stop the current rebase command. Then run `git rebase --abort` to revert it.

Comment: this is the general way to solve this problem, no matter if you're using vim or any other editor. thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

Delete all text in your text editor screen, then save the file with the default supplied path.

Answer (score 1):

> Sure I can just delete all pick lines, but it might be a lot to do if I rebase a longer history. Is there another way?

Yes, instead you could add an error into the first line, for instance remove the 'p' from pick:

```
ick c843ea2 Set Vim column limit to 80 (OS X)
pick fc32eac Add Bash alias for `pbcopy` (OS X)
....
```

- Save and exit (Since you have an error rebase won't finish automatically)
- git rebase --continue (Your error should now show)
- git rebase --abort
- Done