# How do I find the list of changes present in one repo, but not merged into another?

Tags: git, pull

I have a couple of git repos.
One is used for development of specific features (say `xyz`), while one is the mainline (say `main`).

We periodically pull(sometimes cherrypick as well) changes to `main` from `xyz`.

I am looking for a command that shows me a log (`git log` like output) of the changes present in `xyz`, but not in `main`

I tried to look for a command, but couldnt find one.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that by 'main' or 'xyz' you are talking about *branches* inside the same repository.

You can start with `git log --oneline --no-merges ^main xyz` but that would list cherry-pick commits.

You can also launch an interactive rebase, which will list all commits from xyz to base on top of main: any cherry-picked commits will *not* be listed.

```
git switch xyz
git rebase -i main
```

You can then [abort the interactive rebase session from the editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33557899/6309).

If those are not from the same repository, but still have a common history (meaning one repo was done from the other), the same idea apply

```
cd /path/to/repo/xyz
git switch xyz
git remote add repomain /url/repo/main
git fetch repomain
git rebase -i repomain/main
```

Comment: They are not branches in the same repo. They are different repos, but with almost the same content. One is used for dev of specific areas (like xyz) and all such repos have specific dev content. main pulls in content from xyz by doing a git pull on that repo.

Comment: @MarcusWhite OK, I have edited the answer to adapt it to multiple repositories.