# Abort Interactive Rebase when VSCode is set as the Git Editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-rebase, git-interactive-rebase

I've set VSCode to be my git editor as detailed [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-patchdiff-mode).

When I try to do: `git rebase HEAD~3 -i` it opens a new Code window, and as soon as the interactive rebase VSCode window closes the window that contained the terminal that fired off the command starts to do the rebasing.

As far as I can understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226886/how-to-abort-a-git-rebase-in-interactive-editor) the editor needs to fire off an error code to abort the rebase.

I wasn't sure if there's a way to do this in VSCode or if I need to open up an issue/enhancement on their git repository? Or are you supposed to just clear out all the lines and then close it which should be the same? Does this abort it?

Answer (score 19):

> I wasn't sure if there's a way to do this in VSCode (2017)

Three years, there should be a way to abort/cancel a rebase with [VSCode 1.46 (May 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#abort-in-progress-rebase)

> ### Abort in progress rebase
>
> You can now abort an in progress rebase operation using the `Git: Abort Rebase` command.

See [issue 99015](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99015) (from [issue 72576](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/72576)) and [PR 97071](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/97071).

---

You can use it through the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>: `Git: Abort Rebase`

Comment: `git rebase --abort` for quick copying. You have to restart vscode afterwards and then it worked for me.

Comment: @Oliver Do you mean the VSCode command `Git: Abort Rebase` was not enough?

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. With the `ctrl + shift + P` command `Git: Abort Rebase` it even works without restarting VS Code.

Answer (score 6):

[VSCode 1.74 (Jan 2023)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_74.md)

There is a way to abort rebase easily with the internal actions of VSCode source control:

[image]

Comment: It just keeps getting better  Thanks for linking to the release notes 

Answer (score 2):

Simply clearing the contents and saving the rebase that opens up in VS Code during the interactive rebase will abort the rebase as noted in its comments:

```
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
```

### Steps

1. Clear all contents, or comment them out with the help of multi-line editing.
2. Save the document.
3. Close the VS Code window that opened for the interactive rebase.
4. You should return back to your original VS Code window with the rebase command stating: `Nothing to do`