# How to successfully exit "vimdiff" (which is used as a merge tool for "git") without saving?

Tags: git, ubuntu, vim, merge, vimdiff

I am new to this, so apologies about the basic question.

I am using an **Ubuntu** environment. I have **git** installed. I setup **vimdiff** as the merge tool.

I am testing the environment, but I am having a problem.

I created a conflict in a `readme.txt` file. The conflict obviously happens when I try to merge from the branch **develop** to **master**. *As expected, some "markup characters" are added to `readme.txt` to indicate where the conflicts happen*. So, the next step is to call `git mergetool` which launches **vimdiff**.

So far, everything is working as expected, and **vimdiff** is now launched. But then, I decided to exit **vimdiff** without making any changes. I wanted to "*postpone*" my changes till another time. So, I press `<ESC>` followed by `:qa!`, thinking this will stop the merge process. Unfortunately, this is not what happened. It looks like that the merge is now considered resolved and successful, and the `readme.txt` file, although did not change, and although contains the conflicts markup, is now ready to be committed.

Now to my question. How can I terminate the `git mergetool` call, exit **vimdiff**, and start over, as if I did not make the call?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to [exit `vim` with error code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29419286/7976758).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `:cquit`, or `git merge --abort` and do the merge again.

Comment: Can't believe after over 5 years of using vim, I still needed to Google on how to quit this particular corner of it ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -3):

For Windows solution is:

1. type `:qa`
2. press `<Enter>`

Comment: This is wrong. `:qa` quits all open windows and exits Vim with no error code (docs: https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#write-quit), which git considers to be a successful merge of the file. On top of that the OP specifically states that `:qa` does not give the desired result. The accepted answer is correct.