# Cancel git merge but keep local changes

Tags: git

I started a git merge, but made local changes that I want to keep. I no longer want to merge, and instead continue to work on the local changes. How do I do this?

Comment: You were in the middle of fixing conflicts, right?

Comment: If u'r in merging conflicts status, just try `$ git merge --abort`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56605236) to a similar question, since Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) you can use:

`git merge --quit`

This will:

- Forget about the current merge in progress.
- Leave the index and the working tree as-is.

Answer (score 17):

Language is notoriously ambiguous. :-) When you say "keep local changes" you could mean either:

1. keep all current changes in the working directory, whether you manually edited those files OR the merge that you are in the middle of brought them in; or
2. discard any changes brought in by the merge and retain any changes that you have introduced.

This simple solution addresses point (1):

```
$ git stash save
$ git stash pop
```

Here's a transcript showing the affect:

```
$ git status
On branch stuff-217/apply-new-config-details
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.  <<<<<< notice this line!

Changes to be committed:
        modified:   package.json
        modified:   src/wallabyTest.ts
        modified:   wallaby.js

$ git stash save
Saved working directory and index state WIP on stuff-217/apply-new-config-details...

$ git status
On branch stuff-217/apply-new-config-details
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git stash pop
On branch stuff-217/apply-new-config-details
                                             <<<<<< no longer in the merge!
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   package.json
        modified:   src/wallabyTest.ts
        modified:   wallaby.js
```

Comment: Solution # 1 didn't work for me...seems like its forcing me to do the merge before i can perform a stash:

`(branch|MERGING) => git stash save
src/test/java/File.java: needs merge`

Answer (score 1):

First, copy the folder you're working in in case something bad happens. Git is usually pretty bulletproof, but if you start using `git reset --hard`, it's possible for bad things to happen.

Then, do a `git commit --patch`, picking only the changes that you want to keep and leaving everything that the merge did. Once you've committed those changes, do a `git reset --hard`, and the merge should be gone, but your changes should still be there.

Comment: It doesn't ask about the merge stuff. You just end up with everything staged when you get to the commit message.

Comment: @detly This happens even if you started with nothing staged and then staged changes only with `git commit --patch` or `git add --patch`?

Answer (score 1):

Found a tested solution for:

1. keep all current changes in the working directory, whether you manually edited those files OR the merge that you are in the middle of brought them in

```
rm .git/MERGE*
rm .git/ORIG_HEAD
```

Might be a bit dangerous as you're basically directly interfering with git's internal working, so maybe back up your folder first :)

Answer (score 1):

It happened today to me, I need to do a merge in a new branch created from develop with certain changes from another branch...

I tried the solution from Michael Sorens but it need an additional step... `git add .` if you have some conflict

```
git checkout -b mynewbranchfromdevelop
git merge AnotherBranchToMergeIntoMynewbranchfromdevelop
```

it have conflicts, I tried to make a git stash but "needs merge" messages appears, simply what I have to do is to use

```
git add .
```

to take those conflicts as resolved and staged (but still need git commit to conclude merge), then

```
git stash
```

will save those changes in a stash, and if you check with "git status" there is nothing to commit and working tree clean

```
git stash apply
```

and you will have those changes in local directory of current branch without commit

Answer (score 1):

#### Abort Commit

If the text editor is already opened (to write the commit message), closing it
normally/successfully will commit the merge (if there are no unmerged paths).
To avoid that, the text editor should exit with an error (if desired, make sure
that the content is saved to a backup file first).  [If using vim, that can be
done with `:cq`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4323790/10095231) (to discard everything and exit with error 1).  For other
text editors, a generic way would be to kill the proccess, either in a task
manager or more directly with:

```sh
kill -9 EDITOR_PID
```

#### Background

After running `git merge`, the hunks that are merged successfully (i.e.:
without conflicts) are added to the index.  If there are conflicts, the
affected hunks are left with conflict markers in the working tree and a
`.git/MERGE_HEAD` file is created to track that you're in the middle of a
merge.

So the goals are:

- Get out of the merge state
- Keep the working tree as is
- Remove all changes from the index to match the working tree (optional)

The first command that comes to mind that does all of the above is `git reset`.

#### Reset

To reset the index while keeping the working tree intact (including the
conflict markers, if any), it should suffice to simply run the following:

```sh
git reset --mixed
```

Or, alternatively:

```sh
git reset
```

This should also remove the file `.git/MERGE_HEAD`, which should make git stop
thinking that you're in the middle of a merge.

From [`git-reset(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

> ```
> git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]
>     This form resets the current branch head to <commit> and possibly updates
>     the index (resetting it to the tree of <commit>) and the working tree
>     depending on <mode>. If <mode> is omitted, defaults to --mixed. The
>     <mode> must be one of the following:
>
>     --soft
>         Does not touch the index file or the working tree at all (but resets
>         the head to <commit>, just like all modes do). This leaves all your
>         changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put it.
>
>     --mixed
>         Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files
>         are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not
>         been updated. This is the default action.
> ```

As mentioned above, the default `git reset` behavior (i.e.: `--mixed`) is to
reset what is in the index (i.e.: what is about to be committed), but it does
not touch the working tree.

#### Other Methods

For completeness, note that `git merge --abort` should not be done if you want
to keep local changes intact, as it will try to "reconstruct the pre-merge
state".  From [`git-merge(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> The second syntax ("`git merge --abort`") can only be run after the merge has
> resulted in conflicts. `git merge --abort` will abort the merge process and
> try to reconstruct the pre-merge state. However, if there were uncommitted
> changes when the merge started (and especially if those changes were further
> modified after the merge was started), `git merge --abort` will in some cases
> be unable to reconstruct the original (pre-merge) changes. Therefore:
>
> **Warning**: Running git merge with non-trivial uncommitted changes is
> discouraged: while possible, it may leave you in a state that is hard to back
> out of in the case of a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not committed the merge yet and if you have a merge conflict you can use:

```
git merge --abort
```

Or you can reset to the previous commit:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Also, You can get help from `git reflog` command to find the previous checkout.
It's a good thing to return back to the previous state.

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{0}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to merge a branch to current with some conflicts. If you are, follow the steps below.

1. Before your merging, use `git stash` to save your local changes.
2. Use `git merge branch` to merge the branch, then `git commit`.
3. Then, use `git stash pop` to restore your changes.
4. Step 3 may show some conflicts if there have, solve them, and do `git commit`.

If you just want to know how to exit the merging process, try `git merge --abort` to terminate it. Hope this will help you~~