# how to resolve diverge in git?

Tags: git, merge, version-control, git-branch

I'm having troubles to resolve a problem I have on my working copy:
earlier I pulled and it auto-merged a couple of files, they showed then up in the staged area from where I did not commit. I reverted the changes in the files by `git checkout -- my/file` now, later in the day, I wanted to do another pull but it can't, I got an error like:

```
$ git pull
error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
hint: Please, commit your changes before merging.
fatal: Exiting because of unfinished merge.
```

how can I fix the situation? I don't want to commit anything on this branch! I also get:

```
$ git status
On branch dev
Your branch and 'origin/dev' have diverged,
and have 3 and 4 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
```

Comment: `git pull` means *run two Git commands: first, run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command.* The *second* command defaults to `git merge`. If you ran `git pull` earlier, it probably already ran `git merge` (depending on whether you changed the second command for your `git pull`). This is probably the reason you're still in the middle of a conflicted merge. You must either finish this merge, or abort it, before you can do another `git pull`.

Comment: (You might be best served by working through a good Git tutorial. Git is notoriously beginner-hostile, and you're right in the middle of one of these things right now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a `git merge --quit` ([Git 2.23+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56605236/6309)) should help get rid of the merge in progress.

Second, `git pull --rebase` should help replaying your local commits on top of an updated `origin/dev`.

Then you can push.

The [OP BitFreak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12781256/bitfreak) made it work ([see comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61647654/how-to-resolve-diverge-in-git/61650849?noredirect=1#comment109077696_61650849)) with:

```
git push --abort
git pull --rebase
```

Comment: the right command is `git merge --abort`, `git pull --rebase` resolved the issue as desired! Great, thanks!

Comment: @BitFreak Great. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.