# Unable to Open Jupyter

Tags: python, git, jupyter-notebook

I've been working on a Course that makes us do online labs on Jupyter
I have completed three out of 5, however whenever I try to open the 4th and 5th one, its starts my server, however it shows this message before opening

```
$ git fetch
$ git -c user.email=nbgitpuller@nbgitpuller.link -c user.name=nbgitpuller merge -Xours origin/master
fatal: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you merge.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbgitpuller/handlers.py", line 88, in pull
    raise e
File "/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbgitpuller/handlers.py", line 82, in pull
    for line in gp.pull():
File "/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbgitpuller/pull.py", line 86, in pull
    yield from self.update()
File "/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbgitpuller/pull.py", line 233, in update
    ], cwd=self.repo_dir)
File "/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbgitpuller/pull.py", line 45, in execute_cmd
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(ret, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', '-c', 'user.email=nbgitpuller@nbgitpuller.link', '-c', 'user.name=nbgitpuller', 'merge', '-Xours', 'origin/master']' returned non-zero exit status 128.
```

I know its a lot to ask to ask but what does this mean. How do I get rid of this message, that is not allowing my lab to open up

Answer (score 0):

If you are not aware of any local git merge in progress, you can get rid of that MERGE_HEAD with ([using Git 2.23+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56605236/6309)):

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git merge --quit
```