# How to bail out of a merge from a git merge driver

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

We got ourselves into a situation where a git merge driver was misconfigured into a degenerate state (basically, not running code). This put the git working tree into a degenerate state because the conflicted file was just whatever it was before (that is, basically taking one side of the merge).

What's the simplest, stupidest way to tell `git merge` to bail out of the merge from within the merge driver because the merge driver cannot function? I'm really hoping the answer is a high exit code ( >> 1).

Comment: Would `git merge --abort` work?

Comment: @eten: Why would that work? `git merge` is currently running.

Comment: @eten: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004148/another-git-process-seems-to-be-running-in-this-repository

Comment: From [`git help attributes`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver): "*…exit with zero status if it managed to merge them cleanly, or non-zero if there were conflicts.*" So non-zero exit code is already taken and cannot be reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`git merge --quit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56605236/6309) will have better chance of working when a merge driver is running:

With Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), when the external merge driver is killed by a signal, its output should not be trusted as a resolution with conflicts that is proposed by the driver, but the code did.

Well done to the [OP Joshua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14768/joshua), who asked on the [Git mailing list](https://public-inbox.org/git/6e1b9ce4-e86d-fe30-e5de-27a3be57eefd@cedaron.com/T/#u) about this!

See [commit 34d765e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34d765e736e015f5c4790db2c0a1d3ddbd4bd3e9) (23 Jun 2023), and [commit 2b7b788](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b7b788fb31a74bcbff4e4c6efc6f3db6c3a49b7) (22 Jun 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3ea43bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ea43bbe17b9f0d8ffcad17ce602d36ea0668ab8), 29 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`ll-merge`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b7b788fb31a74bcbff4e4c6efc6f3db6c3a49b7): killing the external merge driver aborts the merge
>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> When an external merge driver dies with a signal, we should not expect that the result left on the filesystem is in any useful state.
> However, because the current code uses the return value from `run_command()` and declares any positive value as a sign that the driver successfully left conflicts in the result, and because the return value from `run_command()` for a subprocess that died upon a signal is positive, we end up treating whatever garbage left on the filesystem as the result the merge driver wanted to leave us.
>
> `run_command()` returns larger than 128 (`WTERMSIG(status) + 128`, to be exact) when it notices that the subprocess died with a signal, so detect such a case and return `LL_MERGE_ERROR` from `ll_ext_merge()`.

`gitattributes` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2b7b788fb31a74bcbff4e4c6efc6f3db6c3a49b7/Documentation/gitattributes.txt#L1135-L1138):

> When the driver crashes (e.g. killed by SEGV),
> it is expected to exit with non-zero status that are higher than
> 128, and in such a case, the merge results in a failure (which is
> different from producing a conflict).

Comment: Fun fact: this is in git Q3 2023 because I asked on the git mailing list after getting no response here.

Comment: @Joshua Well done. I have included the link to the Git mailing list in the answer for more visibility.