# Revert merge in pending changes but keep local changes (Azure Devops)

Tags: merge, azure-devops

I just accidentally merged to a branch that I had 40+ local changes on - so now my changes and the merge are together, which I definitely do not want, with a lot of the files having edit & merge changes. I want to completely revert out the merge, is there a way to do this? If not, I'm in trouble.

I haven't checked anything in, I just only want to keep my local changes that I made.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Sorry, forgot about this post! I ended up taking solution - copied, reverted everything, and did a manual compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [Leo BL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11760368/leo-bl). You can try to copy your current project folder into temporary folder. Then checkout the merge source branch and compare it with temporary folder by some diff/merge tool. However, that maybe difficult to cut your changes if they were in the same files with the merge operation.

Comment: I ended up doing exactly this. Took me about an hour, which wasn't too bad, but an hour wasted!

Answer (score 3):

If you merge to a branch via pull request in Azure Devops, then you can revert the completed pull request directly.

[image]

[image]

In `Target branch`, select the branch where you want to undo the pull request changes.
In `Topic branch name`, select a new branch where the reverted changes are created, then select Revert.

Select Create pull request to merge the newly created branch in a second pull request to complete the revert. For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#revert-a-pull-request).

If I ignore something, you could attach detailed steps or flow for this issue , this would be much easier for me to understand and reply.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick hint: Basically, this is a git question. So maybe you should consider giving it the git tag aswell, so you can reach a greater audience.

Regarding your question: What means local change? Is the stuff not committed at all? What does `git status` show?

Assuming the changes are not committed, you could use git stash. I recommend this SO question:

[Cancel git merge but keep local changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913989/cancel-git-merge-but-keep-local-changes)

I would try it this way:
1. Backup the directory (so you have a backup if something goes wrong)
2. Stash your changes
3. Revert the merge
4. Load the stashed changes
—> You should be fine

Answer (score 0):

sorry but you are in trouble. After the merge the files are replaced